# How to use nested loops in order take integers and produce strings

Tags: python, loops, nested

I need to create a function that receives a positive  integer number (n) and returns a string, using nested loops.

For example:

when n = 3 the returned string should be:

"1+2+3+..1+2+3+..1+2+3+.."

when n = 5 the returned string should be:

1+2+3+4+5+..1+2+3+4+5+..1+2+3+4+5+..1+2+3+4+5+..1+2+3+4+5+..

As an example, the following code fragment:

```
n = 5
res = addnestedloops(n)
print (res)
```

should produce the output:

1+2+3+4+5+..1+2+3+4+5+..1+2+3+4+5+..1+2+3+4+5+..1+2+3+4+5+..

Can't seem to find out how to return the string in which it counts upwards until the inputted number...

Comment: Are you sure about the output? Should there be `+` and `..` at the end?

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def themethod(n):
    var toprint="";
    var tmp;
    if(n>0)tmp="1";
    for(var i=2;i<=n;i++):
        tmp+= "+".i;
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++):
       toprint += tmp;
    print toprint;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is head-recursion in python
Here is the code which will let you achieve this

```
def recursive(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return str(recursive(n-1)) + "+"+str(n)
```

Comment: Hey @rajeshnair, your code seems to work except the output should return the string the number of times that (n) is. For example, n=3 should return the string "1+2+3+..1+2+3+..1+2+3+..", not just "1+2+3+..".

Answer (score 0):

A nested loop is just a loop within a loop. If I understand you correctly, you need `n` strings concatenated, each containing `n` numbers.

I have a feeling this is a school assignment, so I wont give you the full answer, but I believe the nested loop construction you need is

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        # Construct the sub string here and append it to a result variable
```

Remember that the range function output is zero based, so `range(3)` produces `0`, `1` and `2`.

I don't however see why you need a nested loop, other than it should be a part of the assignment. You could just construct the sub string and repeat it `n` times with `substring * n`. For example `'hello' * 3` results in `'hellohellohello'`.

Oh, and just to give you a bit more to think about, the one-liner solution for your problem is

```
('+'.join('{0:d}'.format(i+1) for i in range(n)) + '+..') * n
```